# Only one form loads from dll file

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I was just hired on with this company to help them make some c# code for a cnc machine they're devving. The part I'm currently working on is to have a plugin run that will run on this software made by a third-party company they got parts of their machine from. The plugin has two windows forms, a primary form that will do most of the things needed for the GUI and a debug form to help test things. They recently had to update the shell used that will run the plugin and now only the debug form will actually load when it runs.
In the "PrimaryForm.cs"

```
public partial class PrimaryForm : Form
{
    //...
    //the debug form is declared here
    DebugForm DebugForm = new DebugForm();
    //...
}
```

I have a breakpoint here but it's never hit

The only breakpoint that does hit however is in the "DebugForm.cs" file

```
public partial class DebugForm: Form
{
    public DebugForm()
    {
        //the following method is called in the DebugForm.Desiger.cs file
        InitializeCompnent();
    }
    //...
}
```

(Keep in mind nobody CS has actually worked on any of this yet, its all been either EE or CE people so zero convention can be seen anywhere)
I guessing from this that the dll is for some reason only telling the application running the plugin to load the debugForm. Both form classes are public as well so I'm not sure why the primaryForm isn't being loaded at all. In visual studio the whole project, which inlcudes both form files and everything, is output as a dll so I would think they should be in the same file.

Edit: To explain a little more, the issue isn't even necessarily that the dll is running the DebugForm load_event() first, but that it is running the constructor for the DebugForm first and only that constructor, then it runs the load_event().

Comment: I don't quite get it; you were hired to write C# which kinda implies that you made out to them that you have a certain level of C# knowledge, but then you said "both form classes are public .. so I'm not sure why the primaryForm isn't being loaded" - the `public`ity of a class has nothing to do with whether its constructor code runs, or whether the form it represents will be shown on screen. Seeing more code is required to answer this question, or possibly even work out what question is being asked. Post the `static void Main`

Comment: @CaiusJard so I have a pretty good understanding of c++, but not necessarily c#. I also have only worked with normal object classes and having things build to an exe file to run from a main. This plugin cannot run as an exe because it is running inside another application, so the VS project for the two forms is output as a dll file. I mentioned that both classes are public because I have no prior knowledge of how dll files work and do not know whether them being public or private matters to the dll. Aslo because its a dll file, the main is not running at all, which is why I excluded it.

Comment: Does the 3rd party software have any documentation that says what it loads from the dll? A common pattern is to require the plugin to have a class that implements a certain interface, say IPlugin. When loading the plugin, the software will then create an instance of the class that implements IPlugin and call some method on it. If the software you're working with doesn't have a pattern like this, it could be looking for classes that extend Form. The previous version could have shown all form classes that it found whereas the newer version only loads one form.

Comment: Alternatively, based on the code you provided, it could have previously loaded only the PrimaryForm class for some reason but now it only loads the DebugForm. You could try making the debug form create an instance of the primary form (make sure that you prevent the primary form from then creating another instance of the debug form though!).

Comment: @Paramecium13 before they updated the shell it would load the primary form and run it first, but could still open the debug form when the appropriate button was clicked. I also cannot find any file in the folder for the new shell that gives any information on how it looks at dll files so I might have to just email them about it.

Comment: @Paramecium13 while I wait for them to email me back I went ahead and found a way to look at everything in the dll by itself via windows ILDASM tool and looking at the manifest it was ordering a bunch of resource files in alphabetical order, with DebugForm being first item in that list that has a constructor to run. So I added something else that would then hypothetically run before DebugForm and DebugForm is still the only thing being loaded, so I'm certain now it is the very first thing looked at by the shell application.

Answer (score 0):

When i make a new windows form app it starts off with the main form
Program.cs

```
static void Main()
{
Application.Run(new PrimaryForm());
}
```

And then I would load additional forms from events. In this case at the same time the primary form loads.
Form PrimaryForm

```
private void PrimaryForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form DebugForm = new DebugForm();
DebugForm.Show();
}
```

I did run into a situation where a .bat would load the second form and not the first.
It ended up being a bug within the primary form load event that went unnoticed by debugger yet continued on to load second form. It just didn't Show() my primary.

Comment: The VS project is outputting to a dll file instead of an exe so the main isn't being compiled and ran (at least it appears that way). When the external application loads this dll and runs it, the DebugForm is the only one doing anything and for some reason is being prioritized to load as a "main" form is what I believe to be going on.

Comment: could you load the primary form from the debug form_load event? { Form primary = new Primaryform();      Primary.Show();

Comment: yes and no, I could technically do that, however in order for that to work I would need to likely comment out every reference to the debugForm in the primaryForm.cs file. For how things are going though I might just have to try that anyway ad just rework how a lot of things were already set up.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue seems to have been with the third party application. My coworker that had set it up before I started working on anything had accidently told the application to look for the debug form, which is why it was loading it first and nothing else unless specifically called in code.